# How I prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x \sin x$ does not exist?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, infinity

How I prove that this limit does not exist?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x \sin x$$

I can't find two series that disprove this limit. What happens if I use a $2\pi n$ series? $\infty \times 0$ is indefinite.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You'll find the [ability to post "typeset" mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) handy.  Please use the body of your Question to give a full (self-contained) presentation of the problem you want help with.  Limiting the problem statement to the title is more confusing than you might recognize for Readers.

Comment: I don't get what is your function : $x\sin x$ or $x (\sin x)x$ which is equal to $x^2 \sin x$ ? In both cases, the function does not approach infinity anywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ or at infinity

Comment: @DIdier_ : I think the problem is showing $\lim_{x\to \infty} x \sin x$ does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\pi n\sin(\pi n)=0$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi n\sin(\pi n)=0$.

On the other hand,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac\pi2+2\pi n\right)\overbrace{\sin\left(\frac\pi2+2\pi n\right)}^{\phantom0=1}=\infty.$$

Comment: @hardmath You are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: thank you!!! its was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $\sin x$ is a bounded function which fluctuates between $-1$ & $+1$ i.e. $-1\le\sin x\le1\ \forall \ \ x\in \mathbb R$
$$\therefore \lim_{x\to \infty}x\sin(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}x\cdot \lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(x)=\underbrace{\lim_{x\to \infty}x}_{\to \infty}\cdot \underbrace{\lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(x)}_{[-1,1]}= \infty$$